# Prove that $R/I$ and $S/\phi(I)$ are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, ring-homomorphism, ring-isomorphism

> $R,S$ are commutative rings with $\phi : R \rightarrow S$ an isomorphism between them.
>
> $I \subset R$ is an ideal and $\phi(I) \subset S$ is an ideal as well.
>
> Show that $R/I$ and $S/\phi(I)$ are isomorphic.

This is how I approached this problem:

The natural homomorphism $\pi : R \rightarrow R/I$ is a surjective ring homomorphism with $ker(\phi) = I$.

Given that $\phi : R \rightarrow S$ an isomorphism, then it should follow that $\psi : R \rightarrow S/\phi(I)$ is also a ring isomorphism, meaning it is both surjective and injective.

Thus, by the isomorphism theorem, because there exists a surjective homomorphism $\pi : R \rightarrow R/I$ and a surjective homomorphism $\psi : R \rightarrow S/\phi(I)$, then it follows that there exists an isomorphism $\sigma : R/I \rightarrow S/\phi(I)$.

The reason I am not sure about this proof is because I have made an assumption that I am not sure is correct and also because I haven't really done anything with the elements within these rings.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Given that $\phi : R \rightarrow S$ an isomorphism, then it should follow that $\psi : R \rightarrow S/\phi(I)$ is also a ring isomorphism, meaning it is both surjective and injective. " How are you defining $\psi$? Why should it follow?

Comment: This is the assumption I am not too sure about. I am simply assuming that since $R \rightarrow S$ is an isomorphism, then $R \rightarrow S/\phi(I)$ is also an isomorphism

Comment: We would have an easier time examining your assumption if you explained how exactly the map from $R$ to $S/\phi(I)$ is supposed to be defined.  That being said, here's a clear indication is false: if we have isomorphisms from $R$ to $S$ and from $R$ to $S/\phi(I)$, then we would be forced to conclude that the rings $R,S,S/\phi(I)$ are all isomorphic.  Certainly, we shouldn't expect to have $S$ be isomorphic to $S/\phi(I)$.

Comment: I remember proving this lemma [on this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3286917/29335)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a natural surjective homomorphism $\pi \colon S \to S/\phi(I)$. Also $\phi$ is surjective since it is an isomorphism. Then $\psi = \pi \circ \phi$ is a surjective homomorphism $R \to S/\phi(I)$. Check that $\ker \psi = I$, so then by the first isomorphism theorem $R/I \cong S/\phi(I)$.

Comment: I have been trying to prove that $ker(\psi) = I$, but I am having trouble. What is the best way to prove this?

Comment: I know that $ker(\psi) = $ {$r \in R : \psi(r) = 0$}

Comment: But I can't see how any element in $I$ can force the homomorphism to be $0$

Comment: We have $\ker \pi = \phi(I)$, so $\ker(\psi) = \phi^{-1}(\phi(I)) = I$ since $\phi$ is an isomorphism.