# Injective image of quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I was checking the 2nd answer of this
[How to deal with polynomial quotient rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395028).
There is an isomorphism $F_2[X]/(X+1)^4 \cong F_2[Y]/Y^4$. How to explicitly construct this isomorphism? Could this be generalized to fields like rationals or reals?

Comment: Have you tried verifying that $(X+1) \mapsto Y$ gives a homomorphism over $\mathbb{F}_{2}$? Does this help you see whether this will generalize to other fields?

Comment: $[X]\mapsto[Y-1]?$

Comment: @ Morgan Rodgers. Thanks. I seem to have seen that it could be generalized because any element of $F_2[x]$ can be expressed as a polynomial with variable $x+1$ by long division. And it does generalize, if I am correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I seem to have seen that it could be generalized because any element of $F_2[x]$ can be expressed as a polynomial with variable $x+1$ by long division. And it does generalize, if I am correct?

The shift map $\,s(x)= x+c\,$ is a ring hom by the universal mapping property of polynomial rings (it implies there is a unique ring hom $\,s\,$ with $\,s(x) = x+c).\,$  $\,s\,$ is invertible $\,(s^{-1}(x) = x-c)\,$ thus it follows that $\,s\,$ is a ring automorphism. Ditto for $\,s(x) = u\:\! x + c\,$ if $\,u\,$ is a unit (invertible).

That the automorphism extends to the stated isomorphism of quotient rings follows by

**Lemma** $ $ If $\ s: R\to S$ is an injective ring homomorphism then $\,R/I\,\cong\, s(R)/s(I),$

**Proof** $\ $ See e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3286917/242).