# Show that the ring $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z[x]$ has infinitely many prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I’ve shown the case for $\mathbb F_3[x]$ but this is a lot simpler since this a field and hence a UFD and follows the same proof for prime numbers. I’ve tried using that maximal ideals are prime and that an ideal is maximal if and only if $R/I$ is a field but struggling to construct any maximal ideals from this

Comment: Hint: combine that with: $\,(3,f)\,$ is prime in $\,R \iff  f\,$ is prime in $\Bbb F_3[x],\,$ since $\,R/(3,f) \cong \,\Bbb F_3[x]/(f)\,$ by [quotient reciprocity.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1214702/242) Or, you can do the same thing $\bmod 2.\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you are in luck because $(\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z)[x]\cong F_2[x]\times F_3[x]$, and using what you just said about $F_3[x]$ having infinitely maximal ideals, you should see why this has infinitely many maximal ideals (hence infinitely many prime ideals.)

Comment: Which - of course - is essentially the same as my prior hint (which I stated that simpler way in case the OP doesn't know enough yet to prove the above isomorphism).

Comment: @BillDubuque Am I supposed to give my evaluation too?  IMO the isomorphism hint is far simpler than your version. I sort of tuned out at “quotient reciprocity” since I had never heard of it.  By that is neither here nor there, people will like one version or the other. Backing up a moment, would you clarify what the purpose of your comment comparing the two is?

Comment: "tuning out" when one encounters terms one never heard of is not the best way to learn math. In any case, surely you know this is a dupe, so why answer it?